# How do i make the more button go always to more view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm developing an app for ios with a Tab Bar. I have more than 5 buttons on the bar, so on the iphone i have the button more.
Now, suppose i have this buttons: Button1 Button2 Button3 Button4 More (and inside More) Button5 Button6.
If i click More and then Button5 i go in the view relative to Button5. Then i click Button2 (that is not in the More) and i go in the view relative to Button2. 
So far so good.
Now if i click More i go not to More Tab but back to the view relative to Button5.
How do i make the more button go always to the more view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code in my app delegate.m to solve the problem

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UITabBarController* tabBarController2 = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    if (tabBarController2.selectedIndex < 4) {
        [tabBarController2.moreNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to show all the six buttons in the tab bar instead of showing more button which contains button 5 and button 6 plz suggest

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add more button. Just set the view controllers to the UITabBarController

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and it will automatically create a more button if you have more than 5 view controllers! i.e. the count of NSArray is greater than 5.

Comment: yes i know. The problem is how to made the click on the button lead always to the More view showing the link to the button after the fifth instead of showing the last view selected in the more view ^^

Comment: The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar. Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the remaining items. The interface for the standard More item includes an Edit button that allows the user to reconfigure the tab bar.

Comment: I am actually not getting what exactly you want!
could elaborate more?

Comment: When i press a button of the standard interface for selecting the remaining items, i am directed toward the relative view. If i click one of the first four button on the tabbar, and then click "More" i am directed not to the standard interface, but toward the view i've selected before. I want to avoid that, and being always redirected to the standard interface when i click "More"

Comment: could you paste your code and some screenshots so that we'd help you better

Comment: there's no code, this is the normal behavior of the More button that i want to change ^^'

Comment: Thanks For give Important Message " it will automatically create a more button if you have more than 5 view controllers! i.e. the count of NSArray is greater than 5." its really helpful for begineer :)

Comment: Is there any way to show all the six buttons in the tab bar instead of showing more button which contains button 5 and button 6 plz suggest

Comment: You could customize UITabbar Controller

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do is, whenever the user presses more, the first button gets removed and  other buttons gets added.
Basically you can create an array and keep all the buttons inside it. And then based on the button pressed you can navigate to that particular view.

For Ex:

Initially you have:  `Button1` `Button2` `Button3` `Button4` `Next`

After Clicking Next: `Prev` `Button3` `Button4` `Button5` `Button6`

Comment: cool. I am not so expert in objective c to do so, i guess. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController6 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController7 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController8 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController9 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [viewController1.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [viewController2.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [viewController3.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [viewController4.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [viewController5.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [viewController6.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [viewController7.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [viewController8.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
    [viewController9.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    [viewController1 setTitle:@"one"];
    [viewController2 setTitle:@"two"];
    [viewController3 setTitle:@"three"];
    [viewController4 setTitle:@"four"];
    [viewController5 setTitle:@"five"];
    [viewController6 setTitle:@"six"];
    [viewController7 setTitle:@"seven"];
    [viewController8 setTitle:@"eight"];
    [viewController9 setTitle:@"nine"];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5, viewController6, viewController7, viewController8, viewController9];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I have added a sample AppDelegate code which I tried and its working absolutely fine for me.  Let me know what problem your having in this.

Comment: i found a solution more simple, but this is awesome! Thank you so much! For a newbie like me this is pure gold!